# What is the intended use for tf.contrib.framework functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

See the topic, but I am especially interested what is the functional difference between tf.contrib.framework.variable() and tf.get_variable()? The documentation for tf.contrib.framework is not very informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py#L176), variable() seems to be just a wrapper around get_variable().  The only additional thing it does is set the "collections" parameter to all variables in graph, if it wasn't set.

contrib.framework is more or less just a bunch of utility functions.

Comment: Yeah, looks that way. I am somewhat puzzled why all of these functions were bundled under the same module and why so many of them are just wrappers. What was the common usage supposed to be?

Comment: Yeah, that's a legit question.  I dig around a little bit can only say "these functions are mostly used for tf.contrib.layers and tf.contrib.losses", and it's a place for TensorFlow to put these utility function together.  HTH

Comment: OK. I guess this is where tf.contrib.learn hides its magic toys.

Comment: The given link is broken.